# Energy of a system if the nuclear repulsion increases

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, physical-chemistry

I have calculated the optimised geometry for a molecule. I have noticed that the energy of the nuclear repulsion increases with each iteration of optimisation. What is the logic behind this?

Comment: One would presume that the electronic attraction is increasing faster to more than compensate for that?

Comment: @JonCuster, I'm not sure that it is necessarily the electron-nuclei attraction energy which will compensate this. In principle the quantity being minimized (the total energy with nuclei being fixed) has three more terms that could (over)compensate an increase in the nuclei repulsion energy. Besides, usually in quantum chemistry these three terms goes jointly as the electronic energy, so I wouldn't concentrate just on one of its parts.

Comment: And yeah, the question is perfectly fine here at Physics.SE, but it could as well be migrated to [Chemistry.SE](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/). Anyway, just for OP information: now when we (finally) have a rather vivid Chemistry.SE, I think it is more appropriate to discuss quantum chemistry there.

Answer (score 1):

The quantity minimized during the geometry optimization is the *total energy* $U$ of the molecular system *with nuclei being fixed*. It consists of the kinetic energy of electrons, the potential energy of the Coulomb repulsions between the electrons, the potential energy of the Coulomb attractions between electrons and nuclei, and the potential energy of the Coulomb repulsions between the nuclei,
$$
   U = T_{\mathrm{e}} + V_{\mathrm{ee}} + V_{\mathrm{en}} + V_{\mathrm{nn}} \, .
$$
Consequently, during the course of geometry optimization each of these terms individually might go up, its their sum that should generally go down.